# Element does not expand to fill parent flex div

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #2D4256;
}

.nav-centre {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  /* vertically centre */
}

.nav-item {
  color: white;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-content {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: overlay;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-wrap {
  width: 40%;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="nav-centre">
      <div class="nav-container">
        <div class="nav-item">1</div>
        <div class="nav-item">2</div>
        <div class="nav-item">3</div>
        <div class="nav-item">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="main-wrap">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The `main-wrap` div is not expanding to fill the parent `main-content` div, how can I get the `main-wrap` element to expand to the full height of the parent?

https://codepen.io/woooof/pen/VwBLprj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.main-wrapper` is getting by default `display:block`, which doesn't match with the `display:flex` parent.

To get the value from the parent, you can use `display: inherit`. Once done, the elements inside won't respect their width. To fix that, you must wrap the elements, and for making it total height, You can use max-content.

```css
.main-wrapper {
  display: inherit;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: max-content;
}
```

**Result:**

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #2D4256;
}

.nav-centre {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  /* vertically centre */
}

.nav-item {
  color: white;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-content {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: overlay;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-wrap {
  width: 40%;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  display: inherit;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: max-content;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="nav-centre">
      <div class="nav-container">
        <div class="nav-item">1</div>
        <div class="nav-item">2</div>
        <div class="nav-item">3</div>
        <div class="nav-item">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="main-wrap">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a huge fan of making the size of one element (`navbar`) determine the position of the second element `main-content` (`margin-top`). where you have `height: calc(100% - 50px);`  I would rather if the style of the first changes. Say for example we increase `navbar` font size, you would not need to adjust the second manually.

Here in this example I set the `font-size` on an ancestor block to change the nav buttons size and not have to change the content.  `font-size: 1.5rem;`
Change it even larger; again no change to the content CSS;

I put a lot of comments in and some borders just to show where things line - that can and should all be removed for a production version.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  /* stack the nav and the content blocks */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}

.navbar {
  /* put the navbar at the top */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #2D4256;
  /* flex, default vertical/horizontal centers nav-centre in the flex */
  display: flex;
}

.nav-centre {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  /* again these are the default here 
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  */
  /* how much space above and below the yellow border nav container */
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.nav-item {
  color: white;
  /* 2 times font-size for cyan border items */
  width: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-content {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-wrap {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}


/* below here is just for visual clarification and can be removed */

.navbar {
  /* just to show you can style and not effect content block *
  /* this can be on any of the three containers */
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.nav-centre {
  border: 1px solid magenta;
  padding: 2px;
}

.nav-container {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.nav-item {
  border: 1px solid cyan;
  /* you can space out the nav buttons */
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
}

.main-content {
  /* just to show it is below the navbar and separate */
  border: solid red 1px;
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.box {
  background-color: #ffffdd;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="nav-centre">
      <div class="nav-container">
        <div class="nav-item">1</div>
        <div class="nav-item">2</div>
        <div class="nav-item">3</div>
        <div class="nav-item">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="main-wrap">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```